# in app purchase - present price to User

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I have two View Controllers. One of them shows the available In App Purchases. When an user selects one of them it presents a new View Controllers containing the details of the Purchase and the "Buy" button.

The way I pass my code from the first view to the second is the following:

```
-(IBAction)purchase1:(id)sender{
_purchasedController = [[iPadPurchasedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
_purchasedController.productID = @"xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx";
[self presentViewController:_purchasedController animated:YES completion:NULL];
[self.purchasedController getProductID:self];
}
```

So when a user selects one button I pass the productID string to the second ViewController. However, I wanted to present the price to the user on the first View Controller. Can somebody help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: Don't you have the price information in the first view controller?
Send a SKProductsRequest for all available product IDs and store the products array that is returned. You can then use that array to find the price to show in any view controller.

Comment: I did that, SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"xxxxx"]]; But now, I needed to store each one of them as a SKProduct to then call the property price, right? How do I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer to be more complete:

In your ViewController.h file there should be

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SKProductsRequestDelegate> {
    NSArray *allProducts; 
}
```

Then in ViewController.m eg. in `viewDidload`:

```
-(void) viewDidload {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"xxxx1",@"xxxx2",nil]];
    request.delegate=self; 
    [request start]; 
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    allProducts = response.products;
    NSLog(@"Fetched %d products", allProducts.count);
 }
```

And then it can be used as such:

```
-(NSString*) getPriceForProductWithID:(NSString*)productID{

   if(allProducts.count < 1) {
        NSLog(@"Did not fetch products yet");
   }
   else {

       NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
       numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
       [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

       for(SKProduct * product in allProducts) {

           if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productID])
           {
               [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];

               NSString *priceString= [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

        NSLog(@"Product with ID: %@ has price: %@",product.productIdentifier, priceString);
              return priceString;
           } 
       }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Well, first of all, I don't know why but the -(void)productsRequest is not getting called! Also, I don't get it, in the line : for(SKProduct * product in myProducts) how does the compiler know that "product" is the product I want to use? Thank you...

Comment: Is the class calling the SKProductsRequest a SKProductsRequestDelegate?

Then you should do: 
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"xxxxx"]];
request.delegate = self;

The for() loop just goes through all valid products and logs their id and price. If you are looking for a specific product price, have a check in the loop: if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx"]){ /* use this product */ }

Answer (score 1):

Get products:

```
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"xxxxx"]];
```

If it's going to be success, the following delegate will be called:

```
    - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    if (response.products == nil) {
        NSLog(@"No product belonging to the app!");
    }
    if ([response.invalidProductIdentifiers count] != 0) {
        NSLog(@"The following product indentifiers are invalid: %@",response.invalidProductIdentifiers);
    }
    for (SKProduct* prod in response.products) {
        NSLog(@"Proce: %@",prod.price);
    }
```

I hope this hepls for you.

**Important:The code is untested, I just wrote it right now...**

Good luck!